# Textbox border property for a Textbox in .net 2.0

Tags: vb.net, textbox, .net-3.5, .net-2.0

In VB.net a textbox does not have border color property. But i want a control with border color property. I have tried the code mentioned in [this link](http://vbcity.com/forums/t/112792.aspx). By using it i was able to create a control which can be added to visual studio and can be used. It works fine for me for .net 3.5 target projects. But it does not work for .net 2.0 targeted project. The border color does not change.i have even tried building the control(dll) using .net 2.0 target and adding it to project but it didn't work. So please help me on it or any alternative for it

Comment: Borders are drawn with the Visual Styles theme selected by the user.  You can't change it, you can only fake it.  The linked code is a hack around it that overpaints the border.  There is no difference between 2.0 and 3.5, it is the exact same assembly.

Comment: @HansPassant You are correct.But it's not working for .net 2.0 projects. Color does not change.Do u know why?

Answer (score 0):

An easier solution may be to draw a rectangle around your textbox and set the textbox border to nothing

Comment: Yes.but do i have any coding which work like link i mentioned in my question?

Comment: Sorry but I don't, drawing a rectangle around the textbox is much easier than building a custom control IMO

Answer (score 0):

The Visual Studio Visual Basic Power Pack as a rectangle you can add behind your textbox. Look at the bottom of your Toolbox - may be WinForms only. Or download latest from MS